# reading flask.session with angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, session, angularjs, flask

Is there a way to access something in session set with `flask.session` from angular.js on the client side? I am trying to pass data and store to session in the same call from flask and be able to read it from angular later on in the flow.

I am not using the templating system. For the pages, I am only serving up the index file and then using Angular to do the rest. This is my call for the index file:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return make_response(open('templates/index.html').read())
```

Comment: Why not use `render_template`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to it in your template, remember that templates [have access to `session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#rendering-templates) by default in Flask.

```
<script>
var someConfigurationObject = {
    someKey: "{{session["somevalue"]}}",
    other: "keys",
    "go": "here"
};
</script>
```

If you are sending data back and forth via ajax calls you can simply include it in your response:

```
return jsonify(data=your_data, session_info=session["special_key"])
```

Comment: I'm not ever rendering a template... I'm mostly using flask to serve up the index file and then take api requests.

Comment: @sir_charles804 - I have updated my answer with some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Make a service on Angular to read from your server.

```
app.factory('Session', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    getSessionData: function (callback) {
      $http.get('/_session?key=x').success( function (res) {
       callback(res)
      })  
    } 
  }   
}])
```

Return the value from Flask:

```
@app.route('/_session')
def get_from_session():
    key = request.params['key']
    return session.get(key)
```

Use it in the Controller:

```
app.controller(MainCtrl, ['$scope', 'Session', function ($scope, Session) {
  $scope.x = null
  Session.get( function (res) {
    $scope.x = res
  })
}])
```